# Can I Delete All Partitions Before Fresh Installation Of Windows 11

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-11, asus-laptop

Hey guys please I'm thinking of reinstalling Windows 11 on my ASUS G14 2020 model but I'm worried about breaking something. The current partitioning looks chaotic to me.

Is it possible to delete and merge all partitions into one and perform the reinstallation from a USB stick without issues like bricking the system?

[image]

Comment: If you are truly doing a fresh install of Windows 11, delete all partitions and let Windows create the 3 it needs

Comment: btw, having a backup on the same physical disk gives a false sense of security. If your main drive dies, so does your backup.

Comment: @John Thanks a lot

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the tip. I actually have an external backup drive. I just have this setup for days when I want to do a quick restore of just the OS image backup

Answer (score 0):

EFI and Windows have to be separate as the EFI is a different file system type and any attempt to merge them will result in windows not working.

The 1st partition is likely also tied to windows, and removing it or combining it will likely break something.

If your truly wanting to start over here is what you do.

1. Backup everything as EVERYTHING will be lost.
2. Unplug all external drive to prevent accidently deleting them)
3. Administration command prompt  (Windows Key +R then cmd then CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)
4. 

```
diskpart
list disk
```

Make sure you select the correct disk

```
select disk 0
clean
```

exit

The select drive is now totally empty and ALL data is lost.

Reload windows.